# How to pull multiple attributes from one selected element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say for example I have

```
<select>
    <option id="4" data-name="tomato" data-length="six">Tomato</option>
    <option id="5" data-name="onion" data-length="five">Onion</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to call some javascript code later that will take those data-names and length for different variables:

```
var str = "name=" + jQuery("#data-name").val() + "&length=" + jQuery("#data-length").val();
```

How would I do this for multiple attributes from the same element?

Comment: an object or an a array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access jQuery `data`-attributes with [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function:

```
var $opt = $("select option:selected");
var str = "name=" + $opt.data("name") + "&length=" + $data("length");
```

Or simply treating them as attributes:

```
var $opt = $("select option:selected");
var str = "name=" + $opt.attr("data-name") + "&length=" + $opt.attr("data-length");
```

This question may help you to understand the differences between these two approaches: [jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr).

Comment: so if my select is "<select id="selection"> ......  then the first variable would properly be var $opt = $("selection option:selected");.... ?

Comment: No, to access id via a jQuery selector, you have to use `#` key, i.e. `$("#selection ...")`.

Comment: Hey, when I implement this same code on a same yet different code, it breaks for me on that first line, "var $opt = $("#selection option:selected");", the error I get is "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function"

Comment: This error means you haven't included a jQuery reference, i.e.
`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

Try.....

```
 var select= $("select option:selected");
 var str = "name=" + $(select).attr('data-name') + "&length=" + $(select).attr('data-length');
```

Comment: so if you have <select id="selection"> followed by all the options., then var select =  (what you have above) would target only the option that's selected?

Comment: if it is only right that I select option  "option:selected"...You want all values??

Comment: Hey, when I implement this same code on a same yet different code, it breaks for me on that first line, "var $opt = $("#selection option:selected");", the error I get is "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle : [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jairajdesai/Luu07n79/)

In jquery, use $().data('') to get a data property of an element

**jquery**

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($("#4").data('name') + " || " + $("#4").data('length'));
});
```

Comment: Hey, when I implement this same code on a same yet different code, it breaks for me on that first line, "var $opt = $("#selection option:selected");", the error I get is "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function"

Comment: That's because you haven't included the jquery library in your code, $ is not a function error arises in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value using **`.data()`**:

---

```
var str = "name=" + jQuery("#1").data("name") + "&length=" + jQuery("#1").data("length");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use jQuery, there are at least two approaches:

1. If you need the new variables *before* the user submits the form with your select control, you can attach an "onchange" to the `<select>` tag to trigger a Javascript function you create to assign the user-selected value(s) to JS variable(s).
2. If you need the new variables *after* the user submits the form containing your select control, then on the page to which the form sends the user (and it can be the same page the form is on), you could use PHP to catch the submitted values and to write your Javascript variables into the page's header area.

If you allow multiple selections from a single control, watch for the user-selected values to be returned as an array.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use `data()` method to access data attribute value , Example

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('select option').each(function(){
    alert('name='+ $(this).data('name') +  '&length=' + $(this).data('length') );
  });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fem243o3/3/

Comment: Hey, when I implement this same code on a same yet different code, it breaks for me on that first line, "var $opt = $("#selection option:selected");", the error I get is "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function"

Comment: i think you haven't included jquery library.